# Cannot see Countdown Timer Android

Tags: android, kotlin, countdown, countdowntimer

Editted: **Now, I know why. It was because I didn't call it on fragment properly. It's working now!**

It is running without error but doesn't work.
I want the timer to be seen in the text view that I made on XML but it doesn't show anything.

This is my ViewModel file

```
class TotpViewModel: ViewModel() {

private var _time = MutableLiveData<String>()
val time : LiveData<String>
    get() = _time

private var mTimer = Timer()

init {
    startTimer()
 }

private fun startTimer() {
    var remainTime : Int = 1800
    mTimer = timer(period = 1000) {
        remainTime--
        _time.postValue("Time : " +
                (remainTime / 60.0).toInt().toString().padStart(2,'0') + ":" +
                (remainTime % 60).toInt().toString().padStart(2,'0'))

        if(remainTime == 0) stopTimer()
    }
}

fun stopTimer() {
    mTimer.cancel()
}


fun onBackPress() {
}
```

}

> Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Looks like you missed `binding.viewModel = viewModel`

Comment: Do I still need it although I declare "viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,).get(TotpViewModel::class.java)"?
It occurs error when I wrote that line tho...

Comment: You need to send this view model to the xml also. `bidning.totpviewModel = viewModel`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are calling `viewModel.stopTimer()` in `onViewCreated` that cancel timer and stop it when view being displayed

Comment: Where should I call it in? There were a multiple trials to change where to call it but I couldn't make it

Comment: @Lucy the question I have is why do you cancelling your timer manually ?